# Why do I see "ethernet" keyword in my wlan0?

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11, layer2

When I check my wireless network card interface with the command `ifconfig wlan0`:

`ether -my-mac-adress- (Ethernet)`

I just started to learn this stuff, but I thought Wifi and Ethernet are kind of different ways of networking. So I want to know why do I see this here?

I checked some books and it says (about data-link layer):

> Ethernet exists on this layer, providing a standard addressing system
>   for all Ethernet devices. These addresses are known as Media Access Control (MAC) addresses.

I think he explains it but I don't understand.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ethernet** is a family of interfaces, and amongst other things it defines addressing and frame formats.  From this point of view wired ethernet and wifi are just different media -- different physical forms -- to transport the same kinds of frames.

When speaking, we often say "twisted pair" ethernet or "fibre" ethernet if we want to make a distinction from wifi, or more commonly just "ethernet" if we don't think it matters which kind.

In your specific question, your operating system is saying that the device has an ethernet address shown and that it exchanges ethernet frames.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. If you can give me a brief explain in ARP too, that would be great!

Comment: Have a look at [tag:arp] and see if any answers help; I wrote this https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/54597/40371 recently, perhaps it's interesting.  Otherwise do ask if you have a specific question.